# 1 page application with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i am bulding a project thats have only 1 page without routing, now i want to use getStaticProps.

so the only way, I can use getStaticProps its in my pages/index.tsx and its kinda annoying because the index.tsx getting bigger and bigger, theres any method to prevent that? and still have a single page project?

I tried to create new components like - pages/options
and use getStaticProps there and render the pages/options in pages/index,
but the data doesn't shown and i don't think its a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

For the markup, I would recommend breaking the page down into display components (components that only render data) and passing them props from the page. To make your file cleaner, you could move the `getStaticProps` function to another file and then import it into `pages/index.tsx` like so -

```js
import { fetchProps } from "../lib/fetchProps";

// ...

export const getStaticProps = fetchProps;
```